# Python3.6 - Divide All Column Values from .csv by Single Scalar (not using pandas and dataframes)

Tags: python-3.x, divide, scalar

I am using python3.6 - 32 bit for Windows. I want to divide all data in column 0 by 3600 before plotting it. How do I do this? Please see  code below. PS code works fine as is, just want to get my time data from sec. to hours (hence 3600 value) all in the same program.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('C:\Log_data5.dat','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[5]))


plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.ylabel('Temperature(°C)')
plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
plt.title('Temp vs. Time')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You could probably change `x.append(float(row[0]))` to `x.append(float(row[0])/3600.0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could just change `x.append(float(row[0]))` to `x.append(float(row[0])/3600)`.

This will divide your `row[0]` (i.e. time) values by 3600 prior to inserting them into your x-axis list.

Don't forget to update your x-axis label units from `s` to `hr`.